# Forecasting volatility using GARCH(1,1)

Tags: r

I've been struggling with the volatility forecasting for a while.
After digging in the internet, I've came up with a quasi solution. However, the result doesn't make sense to me. 
I want to forecast multiple days volatility in future. The sigma I got increases overtime for n.ahead=50.  I want to see the volatility in 50 days in the future. But it can't be always increasing.

Say I want to forecast sigma from today + 20 days. 
How should I do this correctly? Any tips will be appreciated. 
Maybe I should use ugarchroll instead?

```
  library(quantmod)
    library(rugarch)

    data<-getSymbols("SPY", from="2000-01-01")
    dailyreturn<-dailyReturn(SPY$SPY.Adjusted)
    mydata<-dailyreturn[,1]

    model<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE), distribution.model = "norm")


    modelfit<-ugarchfit(spec=model,data=mydata)
    data = mydata[1:3521, ,drop=FALSE]
    spec = getspec(modelfit)
    setfixed(spec) <- as.list(coef(modelfit))
    forecast = ugarchforecast(spec, n.ahead = 50, n.roll = 3520, data = mydata[1:3521, ,drop=FALSE], out.sample = 3520)

    sigma(forecast)
    plot(forecast)
```

Huge thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.unstarched.net/2013/03/20/high-frequency-garch-the-multiplicative-component-garch-mcsgarch-model/#comment-266

On this website he used high frequency data and mscGARCH model. But maybe it would be useful for you.